# How to delete a file with the name of an apostrophe (')?

Tags: command-line

I unintentionally saved a file with vim with an apostrophe and now when I attempt to use my cli to remove it doesn't allow me to do it because Linux can't recognize it.

eg

```
$ rm '
>
```

Answer (score 7):

It should be sufficient to double-quote it:

```
$ touch "'"
$ ls -l "'"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 May 20 09:27 '
$ rm -i "'"
rm: remove regular empty file ''\'''? y
```

You could also use a backslash escape `rm \'`